# expect script to get its directory ?

Tags: expect

a bash script can be `BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)` but how do I do that in expect script ?

If I use `BASEDIR=[dirname $argv0]` I get the error "invalid command name "dirname".

Answer (score 4):

Various file operations in TCL are organized under the [`file(n)`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm) procedure which has a `dirname` command.

```
% expect
expect1.1> file dirname $argv0
.
```

Note however this may not be set, valid, nor checked for validity depending on exactly how the TCL (nor the shell code, for that matter) is run, so you may want error checking; the directory will also vary depending on how the code is run.

```
% cat dirname
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set basedir [file dirname $argv0]
puts $basedir
% chmod +x dirname
% ./dirname
.
% ~/tmp/dirname
/Users/jhqdoe/tmp
%
```

Use `file normalize` if you always want a fully qualified path.

```
% expect
expect1.1> set basedir [file normalize [file dirname $argv0]]
/Users/jhqdoe/tmp
```

There is alo the [`Tcl_FindExecutable(3)`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/FindExec.htm) call, which exposes the executable name (if available) via the [`info nameofexecutable`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm) command:

```
% expect
expect1.1> info nameofexecutable
/opt/local/bin/expect
```